# How to fail a cucumber scenario

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

In my scenario, i need to validate if there exists 10 objects in a page.

If any of the object doesn't exists, then the step should be failed and eventually the scenario should also be reported as failed, but the script execution should continue to validate the remaining object exists.

I know `scenario.getStatus()`give if the scenario is failed, but how can i set the status of the scenario to failed? Importantly the script execution should continue afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the testing framework you are using junit or testng you can use the concept of soft assertion. Basically it will collect all the errors and throw an assertion error if something is amiss.

To fail a scenario you just need an assertion to fail, no need to set the status of the scenario. Cucumber will take care of that if an assertion fails.

For testng you can use the SoftAssert class - http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html You will get plenty tutorials for this. Call to `doAssert` will trigger of the verification of all stored assertions.

For junit you can use the ErrorCollector Rule class - 
http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html[enter link description here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) As cucumber does not support @Rule annotation, you need to inherit from this class and override the verify property to change its modifier to public in place of protected. Create an instance of the new class and add the assertions. Call to `verify` method will start the verification.

Comment: The specific step which Failed is still shown green in the Report. I need to scroll to the end to look at the failures rather than failure being reported at the step itself.

Comment: @SakshiSingla Ideally there should be only one Then in the scenario in which the verification takes place. Is the scenario also passing?

Answer (score 0):

[QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) provides assertion and verification concepts, where on assertion failure scenario exited with failed status and in case of verification scenario continue for next step and final status of step/scenario is failed if one or more verification failure.

You also can set step status failure using [step listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#teststep-listener) which result in test failure. With use of step listener, you also can continue even step failure by converting exception to verification failure.

Comment: Is there a way we can do this alone with Cucumber than QAF?

Comment: You can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) with cucumber 5+

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good idea to continue executing steps after a step failure because a step failure can leave the World with an invariant violation. A better strategy is to increase the granularity of your scenarios. Instead of writing a single scenario with several "Then" statements, use a list of examples to separately test each postconditions. Sometimes a scenario outline and list of examples can consolidate similar stories. https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#scenario-outline

There is some discussion about adding a feature to tag certain steps to continue after failure. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/79

There are some other approaches to continuing through scenario steps after a failure here: [continue running cucumber steps after a failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298521/continue-running-cucumber-steps-after-a-failure)

Comment: This might be correct, but missing the overall approach. Reason being, say in one of the Scenario step if i want to validate all objects exists in that section, then Scenario outlines are not helpful.